# javascript countdown timer remove hours minutes seconds .. after expiration

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, countdown

I am very new to javascript and I do not know how to remove the expired part of my countdown. For example when the countdown finishes counting on days, it will remove days, then it will remove hours and etc until it reaches the point "Expired"

Here is the JS code:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#clock');
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function () {
        var e = new Date("2018-12-31").getTime(),
            t = this.querySelector("[data-js=countdown]"),
            n = this.querySelector("[data-js=countdown-endtext]"),
            day = this.querySelector("[data-js=countdown-day]"),
            hour = this.querySelector("[data-js=countdown-hour]"),
            min = this.querySelector("[data-js=countdown-minute]"),
            sec = this.querySelector("[data-js=countdown-second]"),
            s = this.gjs_countdown_interval;
        s && s && clearInterval(s);
        var l = function (e, t, n, s) {
                day.innerHTML = e < 10 ? "0" + e : e,
                    hour.innerHTML = t < 10 ? "0" + t : t,
                    min.innerHTML = n < 10 ? "0" + n : n,
                    sec.innerHTML = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s
            },
            u = function () {
                var day = (new Date).getTime(),
                    hour = e - day,
                    min = Math.floor(hour / 864e5),
                    sec = Math.floor(hour % 864e5 / 36e5),
                    s = Math.floor(hour % 36e4 / 6e4),
                    u = Math.floor(hour % 6e4 / 1e3);
                l(min, sec, s, u), hour < 0 && (clearInterval(c),
                    n.innerHTML = "EXPIRED",
                    t.style.display = "none",
                    n.style.display = "")
            };
        if (e) {
            var c = setInterval(u, 1e3);
            this.gjs_countdown_interval = c,
                n.style.display = "none",
                t.style.display = "", u()
        } else l(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }.bind(items[i]))();
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="flex-sect">
    <div id="clock" class="countdown">
        <span data-js="countdown" class="countdown-cont">
        <div class="countdown-block">
            <div data-js="countdown-day" class="countdown-digit"></div>
            <div class="countdown-label">days</div>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-block">
            <div data-js="countdown-hour" class="countdown-digit"></div>
            <div class="countdown-label">hours</div>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-block">
            <div data-js="countdown-minute" class="countdown-digit"></div>
            <div class="countdown-label">minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-block">
            <div data-js="countdown-second" class="countdown-digit"></div>
            <div class="countdown-label">seconds</div>
        </div>
        </span>
        <span data-js="countdown-endtext" class="countdown-endtext"></span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thank you so much for your help guys

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, it's really not clear what you are asking. Have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and put together a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a much better change of finding the help you need. As a secondary note, anybody looking to help you is going to have a very difficult time slogging through your variable names. Use more descriptive variable names!

Comment: thank you Fissure King, but the problem is that I am beginner in Javascript and I got code snippet from GrapeJS countdown timer when I was building small widget. That is why i decided to post it here hoping that i will get a help.

Comment: If you want it to avoid saying `EXPIRED`, just replace `EXPIRED` with `''`

Comment: No I do not want to avoid Expired. I just do not want to see zeros. for example if i pass today i will see 00 days, some hours, some minutes and seconds. so I want it not to show me days, just show left hours etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix my errors and this is how I did it: 
instead of {{ request.GET.date }} GMT-7 give your parameters and it works great!

```js
<script>
    var deadline = new Date("{{ request.GET.date }} GMT-7").getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function () {

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var t = deadline - now;
        var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        if (days == 0) {
            document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById("day-title").innerHTML = '';
        } else if (days ==1) {
            document.getElementById("day-title").innerHTML = 'Day';
            document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = days;
            document.getElementById("day-title").innerHTML = 'Days';
        }
        if (hours != 0) {
            document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hours;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '';
            document.getElementById("hour-title").innerHTML = '';
        }

        document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = seconds;
        if (t < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = '';
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a time period = 0 and all the larger time periods are also 0.

```
if (day == 0) {
    day.innerHTML = "";
}
if (day == 0 && hour == 0) {
    hour.innerHTML = "";
}
if (day == 0 && hour == 0 && min == 0) {
    min.innerHTML = "";
}
if (day == 0 && hour == 0 && min == 0 && sec == 0) {
    sec.innerHTML = "";
    n.innerHTML = "Expired";
}
```

Comment: It is not changing anything. Those IF statements should go after this function:                u = function () {
                    var day = (new Date).getTime(),
                        hour = e - day,
                        min = Math.floor(hour / 864e5),
                        sec = Math.floor(hour % 864e5 / 36e5),
                        s = Math.floor(hour % 36e4 / 6e4),
                        u = Math.floor(hour % 6e4 / 1e3);

Comment: Hey Logan, I have added html section of my code. Could you please have a look again on my JS and HTML. Coz It is still not working